# Trying to add a newline to the paste command

Tags: bash, newlines, paste

Here is the weak attempt at a paste command trying to include a newline:

```
    paste -d -s tmp1 tmp2 \n tmp3 \n tmp4 tmp5 tmp6 > tmp7
```

Basically I have several lines in each tmp and I want the output to read

```
First(tmp1) Last(tmp2)
Address(tmp3)
City(tmp4) State(tmp5) Zip(tmp6)
```

Am I way off base with using a newline in the paste command?

Here is my finished product: THANK YOU FOR THE HELP!

```
    cp phbook phbookh2p5

    sed 's/\t/,/g' phbookh2p5 > tmp
    sort -k2 -t ',' -d tmp > tmp0
    cut -d',' -f1,2 tmp0 > tmp1
    cut -d',' -f3 tmp0 > tmp2
    cut -d',' -f4,5,6 tmp0 > tmp3
    echo "" > tmp4

    paste -d '\n' tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 tmp4 > tmp7

    sed 's/\t/ /g' tmp7 > phbookh2p5

    cat phbookh2p5

    rm tmp*; rm phbookh2p5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this solution with two extra temporary files:

```
paste tmp1 tmp2 > tmp12
paste tmp4 tmp5 tmp6 > tmp456
paste -d "\n" tmp12 tmp3 tmp456 > tmp7
```

This solution was based on the assumption that the `-d` option selects the delimiter **globally** for all input files so it either be a blank **or** a newline. In a way this is true since later occurences of `-d` overwrite previous ones. However, as @DigitalTrauma pointed out we can supply more than one delimiter which will be used sequentially. So @DigitalTrauma's solution is more elegant than mine since it completely avoids additional temporary files.

One niche application for my solution would be the case in which one or delimiters with *more than one character each* have to be used. This should not be possible with just using the `-d` option.

Comment: +1 Thanks for letting me know @Marcus. It is worth knowing that we could set the delimiter globally.

Comment: @Ramesh Well, maybe there are different flavors of `paste` around. The one I use (paste (GNU coreutils) 8.21) only heeds the last instance of `-d` on the command line.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Thanks for pointing this out. I will update my answer. +1 for yours.

Answer (score 4):

I think this part of the `paste` man page is what you want:

> ```
>    -d, --delimiters=LIST
>           reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs
> ```

So this one-liner should work for your case:

```
paste -d" \n\n  " tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 tmp4 tmp5 tmp6 > tmp7
```

Works as expected with @DopeGhoti's sample data:

```
$ grep . tmp*
tmp1:Bill
tmp1:Bob
tmp2:Kerman
tmp2:Germin
tmp3:123 Main St.
tmp3:321 Sesame St.
tmp4:Kerbopalis
tmp4:Kerbington
tmp5:Kerbskatchewan
tmp5:Kermont
tmp6:12345
tmp6:31416
$ paste -d" \n\n  " tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 tmp4 tmp5 tmp6
Bill Kerman
123 Main St.
Kerbopalis Kerbskatchewan 12345
Bob Germin
321 Sesame St.
Kerbington Kermont 31416
$
```

I've tested this successfully with `paste` from GNU Coreutils 5.97 and 8.21 and BSD (OS X).  Not sure what other versions of paste are out there in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

This command should work.

```
 paste -s tmp1 tmp2 -d '\n' tmp3 -d '\n' tmp4 tmp5 tmp6 > tmp7
```

Comment: According to what I tried `-d` sets the delimiter globally.

Comment: @MarcusRickert, do you mean if you use `paste -s -d '\n' file1 file2 file3 > file4`, it worked? I tried and it did seem to work.

Comment: It def got me close but for whatever reason I did an update and it all worked for me both ways. I found a happy medium and have the output I needed. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You might get by combining `paste` and `awk`:

```
paste -d'|' tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 tmp4 tmp5 tmp6 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" }; {print $1, $2 "\n" $3 "\n" $4, $5, $6}' > tmp7
```

Example output from some test data I threw together for the tmp files:

```
Bill Kerman
123 Main St.
Kerbopalis Kerbskatchewan 12345
Bob Germin
321 Sesame St.
Kerbington Kermont 31416
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sort -dk2,2 phpbook |
sed "s/\t/\n/3;s//\n/2;s// /g"
```

As I understand it you have a file called `phpbook` that consists of lines of phone book entries that look like this:

```
{first}\t{last}\t{address}\t{city}\t{state}\t{zip}
```

You want to sort these on `{last}`, add newlines following `{last}` and `{address}` for each entry, translate `\t`abs to `<spaces>` and then print the results to `stdout`. If that is not the case then I can't make out what else your command would do - but I can be pretty dense sometimes.

You should note that `sort` delimits by `<TAB>` characters by default so:

```
sed 's/\t/,/g' | sort ... -t ,
```

...probably isn't worth doing.

Thinking about is some more and I suppose it's pretty likely that your delimiters are mixed and the inital `sed` is intended to normalize them. That makes sense. Maybe like:

```
1,2\t3\t4,5,6
```

...or something. In that case an initial translation of some kind is necessary. So maybe...

```
tr , \\t <phbook | sort ... | sed ...
```

would work a little bettet. Also...

```
sort ... -k 2
```

...*might* be problematic in edge cases because when you use it you do not `sort` on *only* the second field, but rather from the second field to the end of line. In general when people do that they really want `-k2,2` which confines the data `sort` considers to *only* the second field.

It might also be worthwhile to add a secondary key like:

```
...sort -dk2,2 -k1,1
```

...which would `sort` *primarily* on last names and *secondarily* on first names. In that way *Zed Smith* would follow *Alpha Smith* every time.

Anyway, on the off-chance I'm right, the `sort | sed` pipeline above should do the whole thing. I'm assuming your `sed` understands the `\e`scapes I used, but if it doesn't then you can try replacing the quoted `sed` script with:

```
s/<literal TAB>/\
/3;s//\
/2;s// /g
```